# Select distinct record from table and perform Sum of column (Pallats, Gross) of a duplicate row. And show that duplicate rows once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select distinct records from table and perform a sum of columns (Pallats, Gross) of a duplicate row. And show duplicate rows only once.

Input Table data:

[image: Input Table]

Output of SQL:

[image: Output of SQL]

Comment: Please don't post as image. Use text instead. Also show your query and explain the issue you have

Comment: So what is stopping you doing what you want? Do you know about `group by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select disport, actualagent, . . . , country,
       sum(pallats), sum(gross)
from t
group by disport, actualagent, . . ., country;
```

You need to list all the columns where the `. . .` is.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon :: Above query works just needs to put distinct after select command. 
  select distinct disport, actualagent, . . . , country,
       sum(pallats), sum(gross)
from t
group by disport, actualagent, . . ., country;